# Поиск наибольшего расстояния у пары точек из массива

Tags: python, алгоритм

Имеется массив с точками, заданными координатами x,y. Нужно найти Из всего массива две точки расстояние между которыми максимально. Я решал задачу методом [Rotating Calipers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotating_calipers) на языке python. Находил диаметр (максимальную ширину) выпуклого многоугольника, что являлось двумя самыми отдаленными точками, а затем просто находил расстояние между ними. Вот что получилось.

```
from math import *

def rast(x1, x2, y1, y2):
        x = x2-x1
        y = y2-y1
        l = sqrt(pow(fabs(x), 2)+pow(fabs(y), 2));
        return l

def orientation(p,q,r):
    '''Return positive if p-q-r are clockwise, neg if ccw, zero if colinear.'''
    return (q[1]-p[1])*(r[0]-p[0]) - (q[0]-p[0])*(r[1]-p[1])

def hulls(Points):
    '''Graham scan to find upper and lower convex hulls of a set of 2d points.'''
    U = []
    L = []
    Points.sort()
    for p in Points:
        while len(U) > 1 and orientation(U[-2],U[-1],p) <= 0: U.pop()
        while len(L) > 1 and orientation(L[-2],L[-1],p) >= 0: L.pop()
        U.append(p)
        L.append(p)
    return U,L

def rotatingCalipers(Points):
    '''Given a list of 2d points, finds all ways of sandwiching the points
between two parallel lines that touch one point each, and yields the sequence
of pairs of points touched by each pair of lines.'''
    U,L = hulls(Points)
    i = 0
    j = len(L) - 1
    while i < len(U) - 1 or j > 0:
        yield U[i],L[j]

        # if all the way through one side of hull, advance the other side
        if i == len(U) - 1: j -= 1
        elif j == 0: i += 1

        # still points left on both lists, compare slopes of next hull edges
        # being careful to avoid divide-by-zero in slope calculation
        elif (U[i+1][1]-U[i][1])*(L[j][0]-L[j-1][0]) > \
                (L[j][1]-L[j-1][1])*(U[i+1][0]-U[i][0]):
            i += 1
        else: j -= 1

def diameter(Points):
    '''Given a list of 2d points, returns the pair that is farthest apart.'''
    diam,pair = max([((p[0]-q[0])**2 + (p[1]-q[1])**2, (p,q))
                     for p,q in rotatingCalipers(Points)])
    return pair

n=int(input()) #amount of points
dots = []
#input coordinates as pairs with x,y
for i in range(n):
    tmp = [int(j) for j in input().split()]
    dots.append([tmp[0],tmp[1]])
tmp = diameter(dots)
d1,d2=tmp[0],tmp[1]
print(rast(d1[0],d2[0],d1[1],d2[1]))
```

Задача из олимпиадных, проверяется через закрытый тестировщик и конечно имеет ограничения по времени и памяти: 4 секунды, 256 мегабайт. По времени и памяти моё решение проходит, но некоторые тесты решает не правильно (посмотреть с какими данными ошибается я не могу)

Прошу помочь понять в каком случае моё решение будет давать неверные результаты

Оригинальное условие задачи: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPqJi.png

Comment: @AnT, посмотрел ваш вариант , это тоже самое

Comment: Мне почему-то показалось, что изначально было написано другое. Да, у вас все нормально в этом плане и в Вики тоже все правильно. Померещилось.

Comment: Если бы это был С/С++, я бы смотрел в сторону переполнения... А по времени - должен пройти даже полный перебор...

Comment: @Harry , пробовал полный перебор. Ошибки в тех же самых местах что и у алгоритма с Rotating Calipers но плюс к этому идет несколько тестов с выходом за время.

Comment: Даю еще одну мысль - что если на прямой между самыми далеко разнесенными точками лежит третья?... Тогда самыми далеко разнесенными точками они - по оригинальному условию движения без встреченных оазисов - не являются... Вот тут уже перебор по времени точно не сработает...